# how to find and change hexadecimal value in PERL

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find `x0027;` this and change to `x2019;` hexadecimal value in a string;

I tried :

```
$string =~s/\x{0027}/\x{2019}/g;
```

but not working

Kindly anyone give some suggestion to solve this

Thanks

Comment: try this `$string =~s/\x\{0027\}/\x\{2019\}/g;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of `\` or `{ }` brackets.

```
$string =~ s/x0027/x2019/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the curly brackets:

```
$string =~s/\x0027/\x2019/g;
```

or if there're present in the original string, escape them:

```
$string =~s/\x\{0027\}/\x\{2019\}/g;
```

Comment: Its not working M42, remains the same, but anyway Thanks for your prompt reply